# Setting precision of floating point number

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

Hello guys I am new in C++ 
I am trying to write the function to calculate the second moment of inertia and set the precision with 3 decimal places. 
In the output does not apply the 3 decimal places in the first call but the following 4 calls does applied.  Here is my codes , please help me find the error and if possible please explain some details thank you very much !

```
double beamMoment(double b, double h) //the function that calculating the second moment of inertia
{
    double I;  //variables b=base, h=height, I= second moment of inertia

    I = b * (pow(h, 3.0) / 12); // formular of the second momeent of inertia


    ofs << "b=" << b << "," << "h=" << h << "," << "I="  << I  << setprecision(3) << fixed <<  endl;
    ofs << endl;


    return I;

}

int main()
{
    beamMoment(10,100);
    beamMoment(33, 66);
    beamMoment(44, 88);
    beamMoment(26, 51);
    beamMoment(7, 19);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output in my text file is as follow :

```
b=10,h=100,I=833333 

b=33.000,h=66.000,I=790614.000 

b=44.000,h=88.000,I=2498730.667 

b=26.000,h=51.000,I=287410.500 

b=7.000,h=19.000,I=4001.083
```

Comment: Try `ofs << setprecision(3) << fixed <<  "b=" << b << "," << "h=" << h << "," << "I="  << I  << endl;`

Comment: Oh i got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You have to set stream precision **before** printing a number.

```
ofs << 5.5555 << setprecision(3) << endl; // prints "5.5555"
ofs << setprecision(3) << 5.5555 << endl; // prints "5.555"
```

Stream operators `<<` and `>>` are, in fact, methods that can be chained. Let's say we have a piece of example java code like:

```
dog.walk().stopByTheTree().pee();
```

In C++, if we'd use stream operators, it'd look like:

```
dog << walk << stopByTheTree << pee;
```

Operations on `dog` objects are executed from left to right, and the direction of "arrows" doesn't matter. These method names are just syntactic sugar.

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) for more details.

Comment: Ya I tried to put that before print the numbers and it works  thank you a lot